# Is it possible to do a FULL install of ubuntu/any distro to a flash drive?

Tags: installation, usb-drive

I've tried this several times in the past, but none of them worked. First I tried doing it like a normal Xubuntu 32 bit install (I removed the hard drive of the computer I was installing it from) using ubiquity, but it gave me some error. I Googled it and it was because it won't install if it is tagged "removable media". Then I tried doing a full install in virtualbox, with a virtual disk the size of my flash drive, then imaging it and transferring the img file over ssh, so I could use dd to write it to the drive. This didn't work, and resulted in a weird partition setup. It obviously didn't work because the main partition was 256MBs and a swap of 15.75 gb.

Is there any easy way of doing this? Preferably with a ext2 file system to reduce writes, but that doesn't matter all that much.

Answer (score 0):

The normal Ubuntu install should work fine to a 4G stick (even though it claims to need more).

Set up your install media, a 1-2G USB or DVD, then boot it and insert your target 16G stick. Select the 16G stick as the install target and it should work.

I use ext2, no swap, and align the partitions to 4M (start at sector 8192).  I have heard people recommend ext4 without journaling but no experience with that.  I put /tmp and /var/log into ram for better performance (fstab entries), put noatime on the root file
system to avoid writes just for accessing files, and link a few other directories to /tmp, like /var/cache/apt/archives.  Don't know the error you encountered.  One caution, the grub.cfg will be created with wrong devices, so it won't boot until you fix them (bug filed long ago).  The wrong device used to be one too high (because when the USB install media is removed, all disks move up one place (CDROM avoid that issue).

Comment: I have a 16GB stick and it gives me the error with no way to continue the install.

Answer (score 0):

press the super key ( Windows key ) and search for `startup disk creator`.

[image]

it gives you some basic options about how to partition your HDD while installing ubuntu on USB, especially if you want to create a separate partition to save your files or not. However if you are referring to other usage you should clarify what kind of use or installation you are looking for.

Comment: Does this just create a live USB or a full install? It should be a full install, so for example if I put a file in / (not that I would, that would be a stupid place to put files), it would remain each boot, and if I looked at the usb from my computer, it would show as if it was a HD with ubuntu/xubuntu/whatever on it.

Comment: this program creates a live usb for a given valid ISO, plus you have the option of creating a separate partition for your files, assuming that you have done this you will find another extra partition when you boot the live usb so you can save what you have to save there and not in the system partition.